# What is defined as opening a node in a tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, nodes, a-star

I'm drawing a tree for an A star traversal for an assignment. I'm a  little confused at what exactly defines "opening" a node. Is it when I do it to see its children? Or does it include the leaf nodes that I'm calculating a cost for as well?

In breadth-first search, does this include the leaf nodes as well? Or simply the ones I'm opening to get their children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it when I do it to see its children?

Yes, "opening" or "expanding" a node means exactly that, "let's see what are its children nodes".

Comment: Thanks! So it's children would not be counted as an "opened" node? IE, if I have a 3 node tree, and I open the root to see its children, it is one opened node?

Comment: @Wilson Yes, the root would be the only opened/expanded node in that case. You can't expand terminal nodes (leafs), by their definition  (node without a children).